Unity 3d Photon pun 2 material sync
I've found a problem with sync of material.
In my code I want to change some variables of material throw script and sync it between players.
Please note that every component have a "Photon view" component on it.
Also, code seems sync but for some reason, only local player sees material changes.
I would really appreciate for any kind of help.
[SerializeField] private Material holoGatesMat;

private IEnumerator HackProcess() {
        isHackProccess = true;
        photonView.RPC("remoteSound", RpcTarget.All);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.5f);
        photonView.RPC("InitiateHacking", RpcTarget.All);
}

[PunRPC]
public void InitiateHacking() {
        holoGates.SetActive(true);
        holoLight.intensity = 0;
        holoGatesMat.SetColor("_BaseEmissionColor", new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        holoGatesMat.SetColor("_FresnelColor", new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

        StartCoroutine(AnimateHologramAppearance());

        //other part of my code...
}   

private IEnumerator AnimateHologramAppearance() {
    float duration = 1.5f;
    float time = 0;

    photonView.RPC("UpdateLightProperties", RpcTarget.All, 147f / 255f, 0f, 250f / 255f, 1f, 0);
    photonView.RPC("UpdateMaterialProperties", RpcTarget.All, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    while (time < duration) {
        float t = time / duration;
        float intensity = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, t);
        photonView.RPC("UpdateLightProperties", RpcTarget.All, 147f / 255f, 0f, 250f / 255f, 1f, intensity);
        photonView.RPC("UpdateMaterialProperties", RpcTarget.All, 
            Mathf.Lerp(0, 32f / 255f, t), Mathf.Lerp(0, 1f / 255f, t), Mathf.Lerp(0, 255f / 255f, t), Mathf.Lerp(0, 0.15f, t),
            Mathf.Lerp(0, 91f / 255f, t), Mathf.Lerp(0, 0f, t), Mathf.Lerp(0, 255f / 255f, t), Mathf.Lerp(0, 0.15f, t));

        time += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);

    float flickerEndTime = Time.time + 5f;
    while (Time.time < flickerEndTime) {
        bool toggle = Random.Range(0, 2) > 0;
        if (toggle) {
            photonView.RPC("UpdateMaterialProperties", RpcTarget.All, 32f / 255f, 1f / 255f, 255f / 255f, 0.15f,
                91f / 255f, 0f, 255f / 255f, 0.15f);
            photonView.RPC("UpdateLightProperties", RpcTarget.All, 147f / 255f, 0f, 250f / 255f, 1f, 1);
        } else {
            photonView.RPC("UpdateMaterialProperties", RpcTarget.All, 255f / 255f, 0f, 0f, 0.3f,
                255f / 255f, 10f / 255f, 0f, 0.3f);
            photonView.RPC("UpdateLightProperties", RpcTarget.All, 250f / 255f, 42f / 255f, 0f, 1f, 1);
        }

        float randomDelay = Random.Range(0.05f, 0.1f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(randomDelay);
    }

    photonView.RPC("UpdateMaterialProperties", RpcTarget.All, 32f / 255f, 1f / 255f, 255f / 255f, 0.15f,
        91f / 255f, 0f, 255f / 255f, 0.15f);
    photonView.RPC("UpdateLightProperties", RpcTarget.All, 147f / 255f, 0f, 250f / 255f, 1f, 1);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);

    float fadeDuration = 1.5f;
    float fadeTime = 0;
    while (fadeTime < fadeDuration) {
        float t = fadeTime / fadeDuration;
        float intensity = Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, t);
        photonView.RPC("UpdateLightProperties", RpcTarget.All, 0f / 255f, 250f / 255f, 45f / 255f, 1f, intensity);
        photonView.RPC("UpdateMaterialProperties", RpcTarget.All,
            Mathf.Lerp(5, 0, t), Mathf.Lerp(255, 0, t), Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, t), Mathf.Lerp(0.01f, 0, t),
            Mathf.Lerp(58, 0, t), Mathf.Lerp(255, 0, t), Mathf.Lerp(0, 0, t), Mathf.Lerp(0.01f, 0, t));

        fadeTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    photonView.RPC("TurnOffHologram", RpcTarget.All);
}

[PunRPC]
void UpdateLightProperties(float r, float g, float b, float a, float intensity) {
    holoLight.color = new Color(r, g, b, a);
    holoLight.intensity = intensity;
}

[PunRPC]
void UpdateMaterialProperties(float emissionR, float emissionG, float emissionB, float emissionA,
                                float fresnelR, float fresnelG, float fresnelB, float fresnelA) {
    holoGatesMat.SetColor("_BaseEmissionColor", new Color(emissionR, emissionG, emissionB, emissionA));
    holoGatesMat.SetColor("_FresnelColor", new Color(fresnelR, fresnelG, fresnelB, fresnelA));
}

[PunRPC]
void TurnOffHologram() {
    holoLight.enabled = false;
    holoGates.SetActive(false);
}


Did you try using SharedMaterial instead?
    renderer.sharedMaterial.SetColor("_BaseEmissionColor", emissionColor);```

Since you initiate hacking via rpc, i dont really see a reason you need to rpc all the material changes.  All of the copies are already running the animate coroutine.  If you remove those rpcs inside the animate coroutine (replaced with actual code) it should work.  You would only need the rpcs in there if the remote copies were not running the animate code themselves.  You might need to sync a time variable once, but that should be enough for them all to run by themselves
